# how to update registered user information

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am registering users in different roles with asp.net mvc. I will make a page for users to update their information. should I create a new "context" or "Models" for this?

I get an error when I make it from the context and model in the photo. I use entity framework and mvc. What do you recommend?

**This  models:**
[image: This models]

**This  context:**
[image: This context]

**This  controller:**
[image: this controller]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check [how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Don't post pictures.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instances of UserManager and RoleManager. I believe you should inject them to the controller

```
public AccountController(UserManager userManager, RoleManager roleManager)
{
    this.userManager = userManager;
    this.roleManager = roleManager;
}
```